# Difference between passing null and {} in CreateElement in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best/correct way create a Element in React without any property?

```
React.createElement(div, {});

or 

React.createElement(div, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
React.createElement(type, props, children);
```

The props parameter is a JavaScript object passed from a parent element to a child element. When you say `null` means you are not passing any props to that component.

~~

`type` in `React.createElement` can be a string like `h1`, `div` etc or a React-Component.

```
var reactElement = React.createElement('div', { className: 'header' });
```

In this particular case when you pass prop `{ className: 'header' }` , created`div` element will have `cssClass` associated with it.